# How to autofill the login domain in Citrix Receiver 13.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: citrix

Hi I have Citrix receiver 13.2.1 app installed on Ubuntu 12.04, I can log into our company(with app not Firefox) and everything is working well, only problem is that I have to add the domain name all the time when logging into the Citrix client. Is there any way of making the domain name auto fill?